# OpenCV: Making a QR code squarish

Tags: opencv

Following are same QR code radially distorted and photographed from 4 different angle.
There is no other image available, i.e no checkboard image is given, neither the camera is available.

Assuming that The ROI is available (it can be extracted manually) I have to correct this image and make a single squarish QR code image.

How do I proceed?

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: do you already have access to the "corner" points of the QR code (e.g. most top-left point, top-right-point and bottom-left point of your first image)?

Comment: @Micka Yes, I have the access to the corner points in all 4 pictures.

Comment: often, the easiest method would be to undistort the camera image in advance. Whether from known camera model (coarse undistortion) and from calibration with a specialized pattern and a calibration/undistortion toolbox. If your intrinsic camera parameters dont change (like for most smartphones)

Comment: with known corner points you also know that the "lines" (the black border parts) from one corner to the other must be straight in the undistorted image. Not sure whether you can incrementally "test" different radial undistortions until you find your lines to be straight. Or maybe you can find a hint in http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.18.7064